# How do I only return the parent if child has results in Laravel, if the relations are triple nested?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, relationship, parent-child

I have the following relations `Client` > belongsToMany `Brand` > hasMany `Handles` > hasMany `Content`.

How would I go about only returning `Handles` if `Content` has rows, only `Brands` if `Handles` has rows and only `Client` if it also has rows, I am fetching from a PostgreSQL database?

Heres a scraped version of the models

**Client model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Client extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $hidden = ['pivot'];

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'subscription_expire', 'subscription_level'];


    /**
     * Get brands for client
     *
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function brands(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Brand::class,
            'organized_objects',
            'client_id',
            'object_id'
        )->wherePivot('object_type', 'brand');
    }
}
```

**Brand Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Brand extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * Get handles for brand
     *
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function handles(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Handle::class, 'handle_pivots', 'handle_pivot_id', 'handle_id');
    }
}
```

**Handle Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Handle extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'platform'];

    /**
     * Get content of handle.
     *
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function content(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PureContent::class, 'handle_id');
    }
}
```

Currently I am doing the following in my controller to get the content I need for the handles.

```
<?php
/**
 * Client metrics
 *
 * Displays metrics for the given client
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Client  $client
 *
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function index(Request $request, Client $client): JsonResponse
{
    $to = $request->get('to');
    $from = $request->get('from');
    $to_date = $to ? Carbon::parse($to) : Carbon::now();
    $from_date = $from ? Carbon::parse($from) : $to_date->copy()->startOfYear();

    $client_content = $client->with([
        'brands' => function ($q) use ($to_date, $from_date) {
            $q->with([
                'handles' => function ($q) use ($to_date, $from_date) {
                    $q->whereHas('content', function ($q) use ($to_date, $from_date) {
                        $q->whereBetween('created_at', [$from_date, $to_date]);
                    })->with(['content' => function ($q) use ($to_date, $from_date) {
                        $q->whereBetween('created_at', [$from_date, $to_date]);
                    }])->get();
                },
            ])->get();
        },
    ])->get();

    return response()->json($client_content);
}
```

But when I am returning the collection, I still get the related collection just empty.

And how much would it take to add for example a Collection model on the query? It has the same setup as brands > handles > content?

Comment: shouldn't it look more like `$client->with(['brands'])->whereHas('handles', function ($query) { $query->whereBetween....`

Comment: @C4pt4inC4nn4bis no that just queries `Client::handles();`

Comment: maybe this helps

https://webdevetc.com/programming-tricks/laravel/laravel-eloquent/how-to-eager-load-multiple-levels-of-relationships-in-eloquent/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need nested `whereHas` clauses in your main query also to filter your the irrelevant client records

```
$client_content=$client->with(.....)
                       ->whereHas('brands', function (Builder $query) use ($to_date, $from_date) {
                            $query->whereHas('handles', function (Builder $query) use ($to_date, $from_date) {
                                $query->whereHas('content', function (Builder $query) use ($to_date, $from_date) {
                                    $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$from_date, $to_date]);
                                });
                            });
                        })->get();
```

Right now you are just filtering the associated records from with() part but you need this filter in your main query also to remove such records that have empty collections

Comment: Hi, I am so sorry for the year long late comment. But this yielded the same result as mine back then. My question here is no longer relevant to me and I have discarded the project in the mean time, I never found a working solution.